# boost deadline_timer async_wait cannot pass handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

New here to boost, I am trying to get the deadline_timer to work with async_wait (it works with wait(). However, i cannot seem to be able to pass the required handler as an argument.

This is pseudo of my current code:

```
namespace net = boost::asio;

class LDserver
    {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<net::io_service> io_service = std::make_shared<net::io_service>();
        net::deadline_timer timer = net::deadline_timer(*this->io_service);

    public:
        LDserver():
        
        {
            this->timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        }
        
        void timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (error)
        {
            //foo
        }
            else
        {
            //bar
        }
        
        void mainThread()
        {
            this->timer.async_wait(timerHandler);
        }
    }
```

But even though the documentation seems to say that this is the required syntax I cannot seem to make it work. And I dont have any experience passing functions through other functions like this. So if someone could take the time to explain that, I would be very gratefull.

Documentation says:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Timer expired.
  }
}

...

// Construct a timer with an absolute expiry time.
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_context,
    boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2005-12-07 23:59:59.000"));

// Start an asynchronous wait.
timer.async_wait(handler);
```

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html

Comment: Altough there is very much good content in that link. I cant seem to find the answer to this: In the documentation there is no mentioning of binding, it seems to be magically passing the timerHandler without the error paramater being filled in, even though the difference is that this is inside a class. But just putting LDserver:: in front of it, doesnt change anything

Comment: You need to bind the member function to an instance of the class (e.g. `this`)